# Is there a motor design where a rotor gradually moves into a stator?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, motors, electromagnetism, generator

I was wondering if there is a motor/generator design where the rotor moves gradually in and out of the stator along the axis of rotation, or the stator moves over the rotor.  If so, I'd like some resource(s) to read more about it.  The application I have in mind is for a wildly variable load like a wind turbine. If this is a bad design, please briefly explain why.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You ask about motors but mention a wind turbine load - I take that to mean an alternator. You MIGHT be able to create a system where the rotor usually lay outside the windings so imposing zero magnetic loading, and have the rotor slide in as wind speed increases. This MIGHT allow low saliency/cogging/startup torque - quite apart from load on the system - many systems exhibit significant startup cogging unloaded meaning they do not start at very low wind speeds.  Whether this could be implemented sensibly compared to alternatives is uncertain. The energy gained would usually be small.

Comment: One wind turbine had a design using 2 alternators - one for low wind speeds and one for high. Neat design.

Answer (score 1):

That actually exists and it's applied in magnetic levitation (maglev) trains. It's called linear induction motor (LIM). LSM if it's synchronous.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_induction_motor

The rotor is addressed as "slider" here because it doesn't rotate.

More info here: https://e-archivo.uc3m.es/bitstream/handle/10016/13575/PFC_CARLOS_PEREZ_RODRIGUEZ.pdf

It's in Spanish, but use Google Chrome translator.

Download these scientific articles as well:

A Study of Non-Symmetric Double-Sided Linear Induction Motor for Hyperloop All-In-One System (Propulsion, Levitation, and Guidance)

Woo-Young Ji 1, Geochul Jeong 2, Chan-Bae Park 1, Ik-Hyun Jo 1, and Hyung-Woo Lee 1

And some formulas here:

Hyperloop Transportation System: Control, and Drive System Design

Jawwad M. Sayeed  Deperatment of Electrical, Computer, and Software engineering University of Ontario Institute of Technology, Oshawa, Ontario  jawwad.sayeed@uoit.ca 
Ahmed AbdelRahman  Deperatment of Electrical, Computer, and Software engineering, University of Ontario Institute of Technology, Oshawa, Ontario  ahmed.abdelrahman@uoit.ca 
Mohamed Z. Youssef  Deperatment of Electrical, Computer, and Software engineering, University of Ontario Institute of Technology, Oshawa, Ontario  mohamed.youssef@uoit.ca

And the Hallbach Array:

Hyperloop Transportation System: Control, and Drive System Design

Jawwad M. Sayeed  Deperatment of Electrical, Computer, and Software engineering University of Ontario Institute of Technology, Oshawa, Ontario  jawwad.sayeed@uoit.ca 
Ahmed AbdelRahman  Deperatment of Electrical, Computer, and Software engineering, University of Ontario Institute of Technology, Oshawa, Ontario  ahmed.abdelrahman@uoit.ca 
Mohamed Z. Youssef  Deperatment of Electrical, Computer, and Software engineering, University of Ontario Institute of Technology, Oshawa, Ontario  mohamed.youssef@uoit.ca

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not sure this is quite what I'm talking about.  Assuming this is a generator, I mean a motor design where the primary motion is rotary, and this rotary motion is moved into, or out of a stator slowly to a fixed position so that more or less electricity is generated by the rotation.

Comment: Maybe that exists, but I don't know of that. Controlling the gap you can control the energy generated, I reckon.

Comment: I think you totally missed the point of linear motors: they are simply unrolled cylindrical motors, nothing new there. Both work on identical principles. The OP asked about a rotating rotor sliding in and out from the stator - a rather pointless exercise.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica  3+ years on :-) - He asks about motors but mentions a wind turbine load - I take that to mean an alternator. You MIGHT be able to create a system where the rotor usually lay outside the windings so impose zero magnetic loading and slid in with wind. This MIGHT allow low saliency/cogging/startup torque - quite apart from load on the system - many systems exhibit significant startup cogging unloaded meaning they do not start at very low wind speeds.  Whether this could be implemented sensibly compared to alternatives is moot. The energy gained would usually be small.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a pointless design since all you do is decrease the amount of magnetic coupling between the rotor and stator. You may as well just reduce the current - it’ll have the same effect.

You’d have to explain why you think that a wildly varying load would somehow benefit from having less of a motor available (when the rotor is not all the way in). What sort of a problem are you trying to solve? Those systems are constrained at the maximum torque, not minimum torque. It’s easy to generate minuscule torques. It’s the large torques that are the limiting factor, and for those you need the rotor to be fully in anyway. So I think you got something backwards somewhere in the way you analyzed it.

One benefit of this approach, though, could be to minimize the relative amplitude of cogging forces if they are of concern.

Comment: I commented below re startup cogging and only now see you have mentioned it here. I need to skim less :-) .

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen such a system.

You ask about motors but mention a wind turbine load - I take that to mean an alternator. You MIGHT be able to create a system where the rotor usually lay outside the windings so imposing zero magnetic loading, and have the rotor slide in as wind speed increases.

This MIGHT allow low saliency/cogging/startup torque.
Quite apart from load on the system, many systems exhibit significant startup cogging when unloaded,  meaning that they do not start at very low wind speeds.  Whether this could be implemented sensibly compared to alternatives is uncertain.

The energy gained would usually be small, as wind power increases with velocity cubed. So eg for a system designed for maximum power at Vwind = 10 mm/s (a common figure) then power at say 3 m/s =~ (3/10)^3 = 2.7% of rated power. In some systems being able to produce a very small portion of rated power may have some value.

A disadvantage of such a system is that the rotor (probably) or stator need to move axially by about the rotor active length. This necessitates a longer shaft and longer distance between bearings, or a single ended bearing with a shaft that slides in the bearing (perhaps a roller or bush).

I can imagine that such an arrangement **(might** have application in extremely low power systems or in toys or ornaments intended to operate in a whisper of wind. However, if it really matters, it is possible to achieve a cogging free system by careful design by standard means.  Long ago I designed the controllers for 500 Watt alternators used as exercise machine loads. The alternators were cogging free - no trace of a ripple for users. This was achieved (not by me) by careful design of magnetically skewed poles and a 4 phase design.